# How to instantiate an object and make its properties and functions available in Nuxt server (nitro)?

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, nitro

I want Nuxt to instantiate an object at nitro startup, such that the functions it provides will be available in all server routes. How do I achieve that in a Nuxt idiomatic way? (I tried looking into plugins, but nothing in the documentation I could find explains how to export functions that way)

To give more context, I want to use this `initNotesReader` function at server startup:

```js
export default function initNotesReader(datadir: string) {
    async function readNote(id: string) {
        return await readFile(datadir, id)
    }

    async function listNotes(): Promise<Array<string>> {
        //returns a list of notes from `datadir`
    }

    return {
        readNote,
        listNotes
    }
}
```

And then use its `readNote` and `listNotes` functions in all server routes.

Comment: Did you ever try to use `initNotesReader()` inside `01.init.server.js` file (inside plugins folder) in your nuxt project?

Comment: That's what I planned on doing, but then how do I use the functions? Will they be available on the `event` variable somehow or autoimported somehow?

Comment: You can use vuex/pinia to store your function as action(return Promise object) and store the object as vuex/pinia state. Whenever the server initiate, `01.init.server.js` will be called. Inside `01.init.server.js`, your vuex/pinia action will be called as like `await yourAction().then()`.

Comment: Vuex and Pinia are not exactly what I'm looking for... They're client side. Also, I'm looking for something much simpler than that, basically just dependency injection in the server

Comment: Something like `const notesReader = useNotesReader()` in a server route file. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: you can try via route middleware function like https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware